# Javascript to remove 'px' out of position value when asigning it to a variable

Tags: javascript, css, variables

In such a code:

```
var a = e.clientX;
var b = document.getElementById('someElement').style.left;
var z = a - b;
```

the output is NaN. Viewing the outputs separatly i see, that `a` is only numbers whereas `b` is numbers ending with 'px'. Setting it `var a = e.clientX + 'px';` still doesnt work.

Thanks

---

I thank you for your suggestions, but the best outcome is `0` with the `Number()` method (from the other methods the outcome is NaN). . . any ideas?

Comment: Subtracting a number and a string is gonna give you bad results, and subtracting two strings is no better. Tried something like `parseInt(b)` ?

Comment: should consider floating numbers, parseFloat is a better option

Answer (score 1):

The value of `style.left` should be a string. While you can add numbers to string via JavaScript's automatic type conversion, subtracting a number from a string will always result in `NaN`.

You need to first convert the string to a number. Here are two ways you can do that.

```
var b = Number(document.getElementById('someElement').style.left);

var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('someElement').style.left);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = parseInt(e.clientX, 10);
var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('someElement').style.left, 10);
var z = (a - b) + 'px';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
b = parseFloat(document.getElementById('someElement').style.left)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Both the values need to be `Number` before doing subtract operation. The [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function parses a string argument and returns an integer of the specified radix (the base in mathematical numeral systems).

```js
var a = e.clientX;
var b = document.getElementById('someElement').style.left;
var z = a - parseInt(b);
alert(z);
```